# Populating Android spinner with Firebase Data

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am having a few issues populating the `propertyAddress` from my `properties` table to to a spinner in my `MaintenanceActivity`.

The issue itself does not lie within the code, rather with the Database Rules that can be amended using the Firebase Console.

Currently, my rules are like so:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "maintenance" : {
      "$uid" : {
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Which allows user-based authentication when logging maintenance queries.

However, the spinner will only populate with the propertyAddress when the rules are as follows:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read":"true",
    ".write": "true"
  }
}
```

I'm wondering what I need to do to my rules in order to allow my spinner, `spinnerProperty`, to have access to the `properties` part of my DB.

Here is the code extract for `MaintenanceActivity`:

**MaintenanceActivity**

```
fDatabaseRoot.child("properties").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        dataSnapshot.getChildren() to
        // initialize the array
        final List<String> propertyAddressList = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (DataSnapshot addressSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String propertyAddress = addressSnapshot.child("propertyAddress").getValue(String.class);
            if (propertyAddress!=null){
                propertyAddressList.add(propertyAddress);
            }
        }

        Spinner spinnerProperty = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerProperty);
        ArrayAdapter<String> addressAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MaintenanceActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, propertyAddressList);
        addressAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinnerProperty.setAdapter(addressAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

Here is an image of my properties table:

[image: properties table]

Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Again, not an issue with the code itself, only with the rules of the DB.

Comment: Are you sure you are authenticated when you are trying to display those values in the spinner?

Comment: Dont you have rules for the properties node? Only for maintenance?

Comment: Only for maintenance at the moment, yes, but that will change in due course.

Comment: Seems like due course is today. In order to access the properties node you should add rules for them. For the specific rules you should use you have to update your question with how and who should have access to properties (everyone, only authenticated users, only admins, or something else)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated the rules for my Firebase Database to include read/write functionality for the `properties` node.

```
    {
  "rules": {
    "maintenance" : {
      "$uid" : {
    ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
    ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
  }
},
    "properties" : {
      ".read": true,
      ".write": false
    }
}
}
```