# Firebase Data in Android Spinner

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is a follow on from a previous post, that I'm still having a few issues with - See original post here: [Populating Android spinner with Firebase Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49556629/populating-android-spinner-with-firebase-data?noredirect=1#comment86121681_49556629).

I have made amendments to my Firebase rules in order to achieve user-based authentication for each user.  I have successfully implemented this, however, one problem still remains - The spinner in my `MaintenanceActivity` is no longer populating with the `propertyAddress` attribute that is from the `properties` node in my database.

My current security set up works perfectly for adding, deleting and updating records, however, it does not seem to be populating the spinner with the `propertyAddress`.

Here are my security rules:

```
    {
  "rules": {
    "maintenance" : {
      "$uid" : {
    ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
    ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
  }
},
    "properties" : {
     "$uid" : {
    ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
    ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
    }
}
}
}
```

Code extract from `MaintenanceActivity` which I hoped would have populated the spinner:

```
fDatabaseRoot.child("properties").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                final List<String> propertyAddressList = new ArrayList<String>();

                for (DataSnapshot addressSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    String propertyAddress = addressSnapshot.child("propertyAddress").getValue(String.class);
                    if (propertyAddress!=null){
                        propertyAddressList.add(propertyAddress);
                    }
                }

                Spinner spinnerProperty = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerProperty);
                ArrayAdapter<String> addressAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MaintenanceActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, propertyAddressList);
                addressAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                spinnerProperty.setAdapter(addressAdapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

For further clarification, here is my data structure

[image: Data Structure]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the `properties` node you have two ids, the first one is the `userid` and the second one is a random id generated by the `push()` method.

To be able to access the property address you need to get the `userid` and then using `for(DataSnapshot addressSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {` you will iterate inside the random id and get the attributes there.

So change this:

```
fDatabaseRoot.child("properties").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
```

to this:

```
FirebaseUser user=FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
String userid=user.getUid();
fDatabaseRoot.child("properties").child(userid).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
```